# Why Limit keyword is not working in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

select count(*) from `bill` limit 100000;

`` mysql> select count(*) from `bill` limit 100000;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 47497305 |
+----------+
1 row in set ``

Comment: see this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174805/cassandra-cql-select-count-with-limit>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`limit` limits the number of rows outputted in the result set, not the number of rows that are processed.

Therefore it doesn't have any impact on queries like `count(*)` .

To achieve this you would have to wrap query into another sub select. Although such query doesn't make too much sense:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT * FROM bill LIMIT 100000
) t
```