# Cassandra nodes going down on trying to query

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

Cassandra nodes go down and the query fails with an consistency error.

```
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-10 02:49:18,159 GCInspector.java:258 - ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 6330ms.  CMS Old Gen: 2908389776 -> 2987845256; Par Eden Space: 671088640 -> 0;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-10 02:49:27,138 GCInspector.java:258 - ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 8897ms.  CMS Old Gen: 2987845256 -> 3324514112; Par Eden Space: 671088640 -> 0;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-10 02:49:34,948 GCInspector.java:258 - ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 7667ms.  CMS Old Gen: 3324514112 -> 3342860256; Par Eden Space: 671088640 -> 277520992;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-10 02:49:45,485 GCInspector.java:258 - ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 9951ms.  CMS Old Gen: 3342860256 -> 3342860216; Par Eden Space: 671088640 -> 671088632; Par Survivor Space: 83886072 -> 21614264
INFO  [Service Thread] 2017-07-10 02:49:54,541 GCInspector.java:258 - ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 8684ms.  CMS Old Gen: 3342860264 -> 3342860232; Par Eden Space: 671088632 -> 671088616; Par Survivor Space: 83886064 -> 72300944
```

Garbage Collection seems to be taking a long time.

> What could be causing it? How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Try the query in cqlsh with tracing on and paste the output

Comment: Also, it's hard to tell you what's wrong with your query, without actually seeing it.

Comment: I ran 'Select * from table limit 2 'OperationTimedOut: errors={}, last_host=127.0.0.1
Statement trace did not complete within 10 seconds

Comment: Also seeing this.                                                                                             INFO  [HANDSHAKE-/10.117.148.242] 2017-07-10 13:46:24,200 OutboundTcpConnection.java:494 - Cannot handshake version with /10.117.148.242
INFO  [HANDSHAKE-/10.117.148.242] 2017-07-10 13:46:25,201 OutboundTcpConnection.java:485 - Handshaking version with /10.117.148.242

Comment: The `LIMIT` clause might not have the effect you expect, that is C* stopping the table scan after two records were read. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174805/cassandra-cql-select-count-with-limit) for another confusion about the LIMIT clause. As you see high GC I suspect that you are selecting from a large table.