# Cassandra COUNT(*) performance and semantics

Tags: cassandra, count, datastax, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

I know there are many questions about this already, but I have another angle on this.

First of all what I've confirmed is that in Cassandra < 2.2 the `COUNT(*) LIMIT N` works as one would expect - it returns N if there are more results.

In the later versions, however, this behavior was changed - now the LIMIT has practically no effect as it refers to the number of **rows** which is always 1 when using COUNT.

Furthermore, [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_d35_v2q_xj__counting-returned-rows) are the Datastax docs on the SELECT for 2.1.

Here they correctly describe the COUNT behavior.

And [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlSelect.html) are the docs for 3.0 version: 
where they simply **omit** the use-with `COUNT-LIMIT`.

[Here](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/counting-keys-in-cassandra) is the post about counting, where they never mention the version:

What I am concerned is the performance of this aggregation: 
*Does it mean that in > 2.2 it gets much slower than before as it now has to go through all the rows matching the criteria?*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cassandra CQL Select count with LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174805/cassandra-cql-select-count-with-limit)